# PFFile as a relationship Pointer in Parse + Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have one relationship as a pointer, and it just gets an string from the other class, pretty easy ..

```
 for object in objects {

                    var VenueLocation = object["EventLoc"] as PFObject!
                    VenueLocation.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (VenueLocation: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    let VenueLocationTitle = VenueLocation["EventLocation"] as NSString
                     println(VenueLocationTitle)
                    }
```

Whats the best way to get an PFFile from another class ? because FetchIfNeededInBackgroundBlock is not valid for an PFFile ?

Answer (score 0):

I did it by doing an ifNeededBlock and then a getDatainBackground block and it has seemed to do the trick.